# php pdf generator that handles multiple layers (text on an image etc)

Tags: php, image, pdf-generation

I have worked on generating PDF about 3 years ago and used FPDF lib for this purpose. I remember it wasn't great as it was very limiting. I haven't got a chance to work on any other PDF related programming since.

I reckon many libraries came up to light during last few years. What is the best pdf generating lib for php that you can recommend nowadays? I would need to be able to include images or even 2 layers (image + text on it) so the lib should allow to do that easily

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why should not you try to prepare a html of your choice and convert it to pdf using htmltopdf generator. wkhtmltopdf is one among the best. Try to create a html template where you can pass your data and image space. Pass data to that html template and convert that html into pdf.